# How to host popper.js locally

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, popper.js

I just upgraded to Bootstrap four and realized [Popper.js](https://popper.js.org/) was a dependency. I like to host libraries locally, as I sometimes need to work offline, but when I try to use it offline, I get an error `unexpected token export`. It works, however, when I use the Cloudflare CDN version, but how can I host popper.js locally?

(I don't want to use a package manager for this.)

Comment: Can you post the code segment where you are calling popper initialization in your code?

Comment: How did you download it?  Package manager?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [README.md of the project](https://github.com/FezVrasta/popper.js#dist-targets) will help sort this out:

> #### Dist targets
>
> Popper.js is currently shipped with 3 targets in mind: UMD, ESM and ESNext.
>
> - UMD - Universal Module Definition: AMD, RequireJS and globals;
> - ESM - ES Modules: For webpack/Rollup or browser supporting the spec;
> - ESNext: Available in `dist/`, can be used with webpack and `babel-preset-env`;
>
> Make sure to use the right one for your needs. If you want to import it with a `<script>` tag, use UMD.

Hence, if you want to use Popper.js with a `<script />` tag, you want to use the `umd` version of it. Located in [`dist/umd`](https://github.com/FezVrasta/popper.js/tree/v1.12.5/dist/umd).

Comment: kinda fell into the same trap as the asker...but this has to be the nicesest way to say RTFM...thanks

Answer (score 4):

you can use bootstrap.bundle.min.js which already contain Popper.js

Answer (score 1):

I also tried downloading popper and I tried to recreate your problem, and you are correct.

If you check the Quick Start section of [getbootstrap.com](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/) page, you can find the following line in their example:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Note the **umd** part in their link. You can download that file and add it locally and it will work.

PS - You may also have to change your jQuery import.

Answer (score 1):

Download the official bootstrap files by clicking the first link on this page:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/download/

You can then use the bootstrap.bundle.min.css file in css which contains popper.js as well as the bootstrap code you might need

you can use it by using this code in your `<head>` tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path-to/bootstrap-4.5.0/css/bootstrap.bundle.min.css">
```

I included 4.5.0 because that is the current version of bootstrap out there today

Answer (score 0):

Just download the source code and refer to it

Get the source code from [the github page](https://github.com/FezVrasta/popper.js/releases), then refer to it in your html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/downloaded/popper.js-1.12.5/dist/poppper.js" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you download Popper.js though

> npm install popper.js

I found there are difference between npm package and its original source which is here [https://popper.js.org/](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js).

I just download popper.js from its original source and put it new js file. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

go to : https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js
the right click and "save as..."

you can do the same with :

[https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/[popper-version]/umd/popper.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/%5Bpopper-version%5D/umd/popper.js)

and then in your code you add this line at the bottom between Jquery's and Bootstrap's .js link (script) :